# Looking for two specific words

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm writing a letter to a loved one, and there are two words that have been eluding me for weeks. The first is a word for a sort of in-between place, that's kind of like "hinterland", but not exactly. It may also have something to do with the word "forest".

The second is a word for "accept", that's kind of like "swallow", but not exactly. Do you know what either of these words might be?

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE.This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions. Single word requests in particular are required to have an example sentence where the word would be used. Primarily to make clear what kind of word you are looking for. Also it is common to ask one question per word. However, it might be prudent to check the synonym sections of a dictionary first.

Comment: For the first, check out "verge" in a dictionary.  Deer thrive on the verges between forest and cleared land.   Litter accumulates on the verge of the road.  As for accept, there are lots of synonyms and there are various degrees of acceptance.

Comment: ab2's "verge" seems good.

"accept" and "swallow" seem very vague without a context, let alone a sentence to house them but what about simply "take"? As in "I can take that"; "Can you take that?" (Or "I can buy that…")

Answer (score -2):

For the first word, perhaps [interstice](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interstice)?

For the second, the phrase ["not able to stomach"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+able+to+stomach) comes to mind.